# Is there a php library to generate mov or avi movies from images and mp3's

Tags: php, movie

I am trying to create a web application where users generate movies.
They make the movies out of images and mp3's they upload.

The final result must be a movie file eg mp4/mov or avi.

In order to do this, I need a php library that creates movie from these sources.

Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can,
You should use ffmpeg or mencoder.

see this for example : 
http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/

Answer (score 4):

Look into phpvideotoolkit and ffmpeg-php

Among other things the description says...

> assemble a video stream from a set of separate video images

http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: PHP never wants you to count itout of the running. It's quite scrappy! Maybe not the best performing but at times it's the only viable solution to a lot of problems hahah

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PHP is powerful enough to achieve that and I hope you realize that the load on the server would be insane.

Your best bet is to use server-side Java, or better yet, use a Java Applet, to keep the servers resources free.

Comment: Now there's an idea. What Java library could create movies?

Comment: Not quite sure. Never really looked into it. But knowing the two languages, Java seems much more capable of something like this. Good luck.

Comment: @petras even better solution would be flash,so you would not have to convert your data into a video format, but you can store it as a SWF file which will be more customizable

Comment: @Dhruv But flash is horrible. xD And definitely not powerful enough.

Comment: @tylermwashburn ... i would not agree here, see this for example, @petras requirement being done in a flawless fashion http://animoto.com/

Comment: @Dhruv Wow.. Wrong again.. :\